# calling http link from href for a server that uses cookies

Tags: html, cookies, href

Typically we use

```
 <a href="url">link text</a>
```

However, if the respective url server requires cookies, how can I tell the url server to accept my http request?

Thanks

Comment: I guess it depends on the server's setup.
If you know you can set GET params then that's it?

Comment: you mean I might need to pass the cookie as parameter within the url?

Comment: What?
I don't think I understand your whole question anymore.

Can you elaborate on your question please? this is very ambiguous.

Comment: Well, the url will be used to make a call to a server that needs cookies. One of them will say who is logged. So, if the url does only make a reference to a page in the webserver without specifying any cookie, isn't the href  call going to fail? if so, how can I do to send the cookie info to the server using the url?

Comment: Oh ok. Then the only way to tell the other server whatever information you want in an anchor is using GET params… I can't really think about other methods (using an anchor of course).

Comment: <a href="http://mycookiedependantserver.com?user_logged="jose%20cabrera"">Link to server</a>

Comment: But you would have to have control over the cookie server so you know what to do with the GET information.